# Onchange event for <td> tag using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Currently, I am trying retrieve database result using ajax. Once the `<td>` tag is clicked it shoudl retrieve the result using Ajax method. Currently, I tried to use `onchange` method, but after i click on my table row, nothing is showing up. Can i know how to solve it.

This is my table code with ajax included:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function showArtistDetails(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getArtist.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

require "pdoDB.php";
$categoryid = $_GET['q'];
$db = database::connect();
$albumsql = "SELECT c.catID, cd.catID, CDTitle, CDYear, CDPrice FROM tiptop_cd cd INNER JOIN
            tiptop_category c ON c.catID = cd.catID WHERE c.catID = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($albumsql);
// $stmt->bindParam("catid", $categoryid);
$stmt->execute(array($categoryid));

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Album Title</th>
<th>Released Year</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>";

while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr style=\"cursor: pointer;\">";
    // echo "<td>" . $row1['artistName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td onchange=\"showArtistDetails(this.value)\">" . $row['CDTitle'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CDYear'] . "</td>";
    // echo "<td>" . $row1['pubName'] . "</td>";
    // echo "<td>" . $row1['location'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CDPrice'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
    <div id="artist"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The getArtist.php holds the database, to get the Artist Details. I really need someone help on this. Thanks in advance. Currently, I have used ajax to retrieve the album details. The next is i want to use ajax method to retrieve the artist details from the following clicked album.

Answer (score 0):

`<td>` does not have a `change` method, use `onclick` event instead.

```js
function sayhi() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="sayhi()">sayhi</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `onclick` event for the `<td>`. And also set some class name for it:

**e.g.**

```
<td onclick=\"showArtistDetails(this.innerHTML)\" class="change">
```

And then bind the click event manually like this:

```
<script>
var myTd = document.getElementByClassName("change");
myTd.addEventListener('click', function(obj) {
    showArtistDetails(obj.html());
});
</script>
```

Comment: I just changed one thing. `this.value` To `this.innerHTML` . Try this. And also debug your code in you function using `alert` and `console.log()`

Comment: i have tried it didnt even get into the alert messages

Answer (score 0):

We can use onClick event to get response when click on `<td>`

Here's rectified full example.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function showArtistDetails(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getArtist.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

require "pdoDB.php";
$categoryid = $_GET['q'];
$db = database::connect();
$albumsql = "SELECT c.catID, cd.catID, CDTitle, CDYear, CDPrice FROM tiptop_cd cd INNER JOIN
            tiptop_category c ON c.catID = cd.catID WHERE c.catID = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($albumsql);
// $stmt->bindParam("catid", $categoryid);
$stmt->execute(array($categoryid));

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Album Title</th>
<th>Released Year</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>";

while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr style=\"cursor: pointer;\">";
    // echo "<td>" . $row1['artistName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td onclick=\"showArtistDetails(this.value)\">" . $row['CDTitle'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CDYear'] . "</td>";
    // echo "<td>" . $row1['pubName'] . "</td>";
    // echo "<td>" . $row1['location'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CDPrice'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
    <div id="artist"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried but I am getting this error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: showArtistDetails is not defined`. Can i know how to solve this.